# How do I ask Firestore to auto-generate the document ID but with a certain number of length?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Currently the auto-id generates 20 digits unique code.
I don't have that much data and I want to make it more efficient. So I want to see if I can ask Firestore to generate a 5 or 6 digits unique id for me.

Is that possible?

Comment: make what more efficient?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood The answer already given below but just to answer your question. saving 10 bytes doesn't seem much, but imagine if you can save 10 Bytes for each read in database and storage (since the filename also uses the document ID) times thousands of reads times thousands of users per day. Then scale it up

Comment: Ok, I've scaled it up. In a year where are we? Database storage is cheap, developer time not so much. Checking the database to see if an ID has already been used would seem to cost more to me then simply storing the additional characters. But good luck either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-generated IDs that Firestore can create are always going to be 20 characters long.

They are *this* long because Firestore uses their length to statistically guarantee they're unique: with this length there is no statistical chance that two clients will ever generate the same ID.

If you want to give your documents shorter IDs, you will:

1. Have to generate your own IDs.
2. Check against the database to see if that ID isn't already used.

This is definitely possible, but not built into any Cloud Firestore SDK, because the second step would significantly reduce performance, and also wouldn't work when the client is not connected to a server.

Comment: Or you could simply truncate the generated ID to the number of characters desired.  `doc()` with no parameters will give you a reference with a random ID to work with.

Comment: Good point Doug. As long as you still perform step 2, that would work too.

Comment: I am looking in my database in my users collection, and am seeing a auto-generated id that is 28 chars long, and this seems to be consistent throughout the whole collection. Did this change? This is super important for a size calculation I am doing.

Comment: I just checked and still get **Firestore** IDs of 20 characters. Since you mention a `users` table, are you sure your keys aren't UIDs, which are generated by Firebase **Authentication** and not by Firestore?

Comment: That is exactly it! Thanks for clearing that up.